# Override standart calendar on Wordpress? Change link by click

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

As we know, we have standart calendar on WP and it's working like that:
when we adding some post or news there are appear links to the page with all post by the date we choose at calendar.

For example, if we click on May 30 2016, we will redirect to
**`OurSite.com/2016/04/30`**

how can I override this function and I need to when you click on any date you will go to your certain link, for example:
**

```
link.com/api/{date}   
link.com/api/2016-04-30  
link.com/api/2016-05-12
```

**